# Accessing HTML Element in an Alpacajs Generated form and making content contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, contenteditable, alpacajs

I want to make HTML elements of a dynamically generated form by Alpacajs as editable in-place. I didnot find the options in Alpaca form API elements where I could pass in the contentEditable = true option.
So, I am doing the following work around:

After the form has been generated by Alpaca,I am trying to access HTML elements within an Alpaca form by its ID so that I can set that element's attribute contentEditable = true.

However, I am not able to access any element inside the form using $('#myElementId'). Note that I know the all the elements Ids as I passed them to the element's options. As I inspect the HTML page after form generation, I see the each form element is wrapped within several div's classes by alpaca. Could this be a reason for not able to access HTML element within an alpaca form?
The screen shot below is the HTML inspect of the alpaca form generated. the id is 'preview0' and label is 'grit1'. I am trying to make this editable. 
I would appreciate any help or insights in this regard. 
[HTML inspect of alpaca form generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4nhV.png)

Comment: Could you be more specific about the fields where you want to enable content editable? are you talking about the label of the field or the field it self?

Comment: I want to make both label and field contents both editable. In the screen shot link in the problem description, I should be able to change the label, i.e. "I have overcome ...",  and also the options's label and it's corresponding value in the select, i.e., "Very much like me".

Comment: I am able to make the form's text and radio element (both label and content) editable by making $('#form').attr({contentEditable:"true"}) which sets attribute for entire form as editable. However, I am still not able to select specific element inside the form by its ID. Also, the select element label is editable now but not its options' label and value.

Comment: I'm working on your problem, I know how to change labels in alpaca by using handlebars templates, but I still don't know how to do it for the select box...and about selecting fields, alpaca has a function for that, you could even map fields to variables in the postprocess function of alpaca ("postRender": function(control) { var field = control.childrenByPropertyId["feld_id"];)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the postprocess function. I will give it a try.

Comment: Leveraged this example in the alpaca website to make the alpaca fields editable: http://www.alpacajs.org/demos/form-builder/form-builder.html.